# Confused about basic of image

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Hello I tried to work a problem from the text called " Introduction to Real Analysis" by Robert G Bartle and Donald Sherbert and I encountered a small difficulty.

I am starting to think that my knowledge is very lacking and I may really need to go back and start fresh, for example, one of the questions simply states,

Let $g(x)=x^2$ and $f(x)=x+2$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and let $h = g \bullet f.$

Then find the direct image h(E) were $$E=\{ x \in \mathbb{R} : 1 \le x \le 2\}$$ and find $f^{-1}(G)$ where $$G= \{x \in \mathbb{R} : 1 \le x \le 4\}.$$

What I thought was,

$$h(x)=g(x+2)=(x+2)^{2}$$ so our image would be say $$h(E)=\{ 9 \le h(x) \le 16 \}$$ and $$f^{-1}(G)=\{-4 \le x \le 0\}$$

Well the answer book says my second part with f inverse is correct however, for the first part it says;

$f(E)=[2,3]$, so $h(E)=g(f(E))=g([2,3])=[4,9]$

I just am very confused. I don't really understand this, and I want to know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Seems like there is a mistake in the book

Comment: The answer your book gives is confusing: $f(E) = \{x+2 \in \mathbb{R} : 1 \leq x \leq 2\}=[3,4]$, not $[2,3]$.

Comment: Thanks, And @ColdNumber is the answer just confusing or is it wrong? PS: Thanks for letting me know, should I delete this question?

Comment: I meant it's wrong, so I though I'd point out where your book made a mistake.

Comment: And about deleting, I'm not sure because I haven't been on the site for very long, but I searched meta and found this: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/15105/is-there-a-policy-regarding-the-deletion-of-ones-own-question.

Answer (score 0):

The book is wrong.g•f(x)=g(f(x))=g(x+2)=(x+2)^2=h(x)
h(1)=(1+2)^2=3^2=9
h(2)=(2+2)^2=4^2=16
h([1,2])=[9,16]
The definition , without minding the restriction [1,2] , states that , because f:R->R and g:R->R , g•f:R->R.There is nothing else to consider.
f(1)=1+2=3
f(3)=2+2=4
f(E)=f([1,2])=[3,4] not [2,3]
If we continue to solve using the way the book suggested : g(f(E))=g([3,4])
g(3)=3^2=9
g(4)=4^2=16
g([3,4])=[9,16] not [4,9]
Your answer is right and the book wrong.